# Point-in-time restoration size VS Database data size

Tags: sql, azure, azure-storage, pitr

My question is very simple. I'm configuring Point-in-time Restore for an Azure SQL Database. Does the size of the storage data must be the same as the size of the database?

i.e. If my storage data is 100GB, does my Point-in-time Restore need to be 100GB too?

Thank you!

Comment: no, but how did you come to that idea?

Comment: Also a good read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/automated-backups-overview?view=azuresql and they write there the data willl be compressed

Comment: @nbk I just simply ask my self: What happen if a put 100GB for my storage and 20 for the PITR and one day I got a crash and my storage data is at 40GB out of 100GB.  Will I miss 20GB od space to properly recover? Is there a link between those two settings? If not, how do you compute the correct size of PITR?

Comment: you must read the docs see https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/azure-sql-database-point-in-time-restore/ basically you have a full backup and multiple  differential, so the restore will tale the last full backup and add the differences toill th pint of time you choose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the size of the storage data does not have to be the same as the size of the database for Point-in-time Restore in Azure SQL Database.

Point-in-time Restore allows you to restore a database to a specific point in time within the retention period. The retention period is the time period during which you can restore the database. The size of the storage data depends on the amount of data changes during the retention period.

For more information, you can refer to the "[Restore a database from a backup in Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/recovery-using-backups?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-portal)" article.

Comment: That's very kind. Thank you!